# Failed to instantiate c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource on local machine

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat8

I'm trying to run locally a maven-built, spring app connecting to a PostgreSQL db. When deploying on a remote server (using our server build profile) everything is fine. My local database is set up according to provided instructions as well. We are using tomcat 8.5. Trying to deploy the war on my local machine ends up in a following errors (these are already coming from tomcat):

```
SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [myartifactname.application.listener.KillBackgroundThreadsListener]



 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [hibernate/hibernate.xml]:

  Cannot resolve reference to bean 'proxyDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource';

    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

    Error creating bean with name 'proxyDataSource' defined in class path resource [hibernate/hibernate.xml]:

    Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource';

        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

        Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [hibernate/hibernate.xml]:

        Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mainDataSource' while setting bean property 'targetDataSource';

            nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

            Error creating bean with name 'mainDataSource' defined in class path resource [hibernate/hibernate.xml]:

            Instantiation of bean failed;

                nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:

                Failed to instantiate [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]:

                Constructor threw exception;

                    nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

`c3p0`'s version in local maven repository is 0.9.5.2, whereas in root pom it's 0.9.1.2, and that's also the highest available version in our company's repo. Changing the version in pom to 0.9.5.2 results in the project not compiling at all. The project is multi-module and one of the modules seems to download other version than stated in root pom. Root pom is the only place where this artifact version is defined.

How should I resolve this? Could you point me to some maven documentation hints?

Comment: this all was caused by another transitive dependency (namely quartz), which demands newest (0.9.5.2) version. Those two c3p0 versions (0.9.1.2 and 0.9.5.2) have also different package names. That somehow messed up loading classes at my machine. 
Resolving the issue demanded using newest version for the whole project, and specifying the exact, newest package name everywhere (in root pom as well as in modules).

Comment: Should I close the question?

Comment: Thanks, mate. same problem your solution worked for me.